# C++ Pointer to const

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, constants

Why 1 is error and 2 is legal.

This code is taken from C++ primer 5th edition, There is not much detail on this[Edit: This is not a duplicate question, The so-called original question is very generic]

```
const double pi = 3.14;
const double *cptr = &pi;
*cptr = 42;   // 1
double dval = 3.14;
cptr = &dval;  // 2
```

Answer (score 4):

`cptr` is a pointer to a constant double. Initially it points to the constant double pi. `*cptr = 42;` will try to change the value of pi. However since pi is a constant value, it can't be changed.

`cptr = &dval;` changes the value of cptr, namely it now contains the address of val. This is allowed since cptr is not a constant pointer.

Answer (score 0):

Because `cptr` is *a pointer to a double constant*.

When doing `*cptr = 42;` you are trying to change the variable, which `cptr` points at, so you are trying to change the value of `pi`, which is a constant.

When you do `cptr = &dval;` you reassign the pointer to point at a completely new thing, which is fine, since `cptr` is not a `const` pointer.